# how to update pip3 for python 3 while python 2 is also installed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, upgrade

I have both python installed on Win7:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.11

pip3 --version
pip 7.1.2 from c:\python34\lib\site-packages  <python 3.4>

pip --version
pip 9.0.0 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages <python 2.7>
```

When I use `pip3 install wheel`,I was told to use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade.
However, this code only upgrade the `pip`, not `pip3`.

So how can I update `pip3`?

---

`pip3 install --update pip` seems not work

[image]

Comment: `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @furas sorry, the screenshot shows not work

Comment: It works on Linux. But you use Windows and you have problem with access to file `pip3.exe`. Maybe because when you run `pip3 install --upgrade pip` then you use `pip3.exe install --upgrade pip` and system can't replace running file `pip3.exe`.

Comment: so maybe I uninstall python 3, and install it again?

Comment: you get Python3 with the same old pip3. Did you try second method `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` ?

Comment: also not work, sorry

Comment: you could try to copy/duplicate  `pip3.exe` to different name and run this file with new name. Then you don't run oryginal `pip3.exe` so maybe system will no have problem with removing oryginal `pip3.exe`

Comment: I am unstalling the python 3.4 and installing the 3.6 now.........

Comment: Look, read your damn error message -- it says there are permissions problems. Fix those.

Answer (score 3):

`$ pip3 install --upgrade pip`

will do it.

```
501 $ pip3 install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 865kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.2
Successfully installed pip-9.0.0
502 $ pip3 version
ERROR: unknown command "version"
503 $ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
504 $
```

Comment: Oddly, mine shows does work. Maybe you need to check your installation of Python.

Answer (score 2):

Use `python3` instead of `python` as:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: @lanselibai: Did you checked the error? It clearly says you do not have access. Try installing it using `sudo` permission

Comment: using "sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip", I was told: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I am not much familiar with windows machine, I am not the right person to comment on this. Sorry :(